# Boundary Value Heat Equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I know I'm supposed to use separation of variables for this problem, but it's been irking me for a while and I'm not entirely certain if this problem is particular or if I'm doing something wrong. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Solve the initial boundary value problem for the heat equation
\begin{align*}
u_t & = cu_{xx},\, 0<x<1,\, t>0, \\
u(0,t) & = u(1,t) = 0, \\
u(x,0) & = 10x^3(1-x), \, 0<x<1
\end{align*}
I know via separation of variables that I should end up with:
$$\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)}= c\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}$$
but it doesn't seem like my strategy follows afterwards for this problem.

Comment: You could still do it. Assuming $c>0$, first solve $X''(x) = \frac{\lambda}{c}X(x)$; with the given boundary conditions, you should get $X_n(x) = \sin(n\pi x)$, with $\lambda=-cn^2\pi^2$. Substituting this into the initial condition, you will now have to solve for $A_n$ the following equation $10x^3(1-x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty A_n\sin(n\pi x)$.

Comment: I think things work more smoothly in these problems if one puts the $c$ on the $T$ side of the equation.

Comment: @B.Goddard I understand. This is how the problem was stated; not sure what the typical notation would look like.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{T'}{T}=c\frac{X''}{X}=-\lambda$$
$$T(t)=ce^{-\lambda{t}}$$
$$X''+\frac{\lambda}{c}X=0$$
$$X(x)=A\sin\Big(\frac{\lambda}{c}x\Big)+B\cos\Big(\frac{\lambda}{c}x\Big)$$
$$u=\Big(A'\sin\Big(\frac{\lambda}{c}x\Big)+B'\cos\Big(\frac{\lambda}{c}x\Big)\Big)e^{-\lambda{t}}$$
$$u(0, t)=0$$
gives
$$B=0$$
$$u(1, t)=0$$
gives
$$\sin\Big(\frac{\lambda}{c}\Big)=0$$
or
$$\lambda_{n}=\pi{n}c, n\in\mathbb{Z}$$
The most general solution may be then written as
$$u(t, x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_{n}\sin\big(\pi{n}x\big)e^{-\pi{n}c{t}}$$
At $t=0$ you have
$$u(0, x)=f(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}c_{n}\sin\big(\pi{n}x\big)$$
The set of functions $\{\sin\big(\pi{n}x\big)\}_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}$ forms the countable basis for the infinite dimentional Hilbert space, namely $\mathbb{L}^{2}[0, 1]$
$$\int_{[0, 1]}\sin\big(\pi{n}x\big)\sin\big(\pi{m}x\big)dx=\delta_{n, m}$$
Hence you can extract the coefficients via the inner product
$$c_{n}=\int_{[0, 1]}f(x)\sin(\pi{n}x)dx$$

Comment: This was extremely helpful and I thought you explained the steps really well. Thank you!